# SQL Server Query to Pivot using CASE Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following data:

```
763b44e57b39-16e5bb772ac    November Monthly Mailer MM_10 191201-1  2019-12-01 00:00:00.000 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000
763b44e57b39-16e5bb772ac    November Monthly Mailer MM_10 191208-2  2019-12-01 00:00:00.000 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000
763b44e57b39-16e5bb772ac    November Monthly Mailer MM_10 191215-3  2019-12-01 00:00:00.000 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000
763b44e57b39-16e5bb772ac    November Monthly Mailer MM_10 191222-4  2019-12-01 00:00:00.000 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000
763b57fe9950-16dac7db279    October Monthly Mailer  MM_10 191001-1  2019-10-01 00:00:00.000 2019-11-01 00:00:00.000
763b57fe9950-16dac7db279    October Monthly Mailer  MM_10 191008-2  2019-10-01 00:00:00.000 2019-11-01 00:00:00.000
763b57fe9950-16dac7db279    October Monthly Mailer  MM_10 191015-3  2019-10-01 00:00:00.000 2019-11-01 00:00:00.000
763b57fe9950-16dac7db279    October Monthly Mailer  MM_10 191022-4  2019-10-01 00:00:00.000 2019-11-01 00:00:00.000
763b57ff55b7-16dad4ef4b8    November Monthly Mailer MM_10 191101-1  2019-11-01 00:00:00.000 2019-12-01 00:00:00.000
763b57ff55b7-16dad4ef4b8    November Monthly Mailer MM_10 191108-2  2019-11-01 00:00:00.000 2019-12-01 00:00:00.000
763b57ff55b7-16dad4ef4b8    November Monthly Mailer MM_10 191115-3  2019-11-01 00:00:00.000 2019-12-01 00:00:00.000
763b57ff55b7-16dad4ef4b8    November Monthly Mailer MM_10 191122-4  2019-11-01 00:00:00.000 2019-12-01 00:00:00.000
763b5803a370-16dcb7cfd7e    11th Anniversary Celebration SBR    $15 Sky Ute Loot    2019-11-01 00:00:00.000 2019-11-02 00:00:00.000
```

I need to create a Pivot using `CASE` statement so that the results looks like:

```
763b44e57b39-16e5bb772ac MM_10 191201-1 MM_10 191208-2 MM_10 191215-3  MM_10 191222-4
763b57fe9950-16dac7db279 MM_10 191001-1 MM_10 191008-2 MM_10 191015-3  MM_10 191022-4
```

What's the best way to do this using a `CASE` statement?

Comment: You probably mean `case` _expression_.

Comment: Sample data like 1, 2 and 3 are much easier to read than 763b44e57b39-16e5bb772ac, 763b44e57b39-16e5bb722ac and 763b44e57b39-16e4bb772ac. Make it easy to assist you!

Comment: Do all rows for a group have same date?

Comment: Does your data have column names?

Comment: No the dates are different with each row.

Comment: Yes columns names: Campaign_id, Campaign_name, Offer_name, Offer_start_date, Offer_end_date

Comment: What's your ultimate use for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you use ROW_NUMBER to generate a sequential number, then that can be used in the conditional aggregations.

```
SELECT Campaign_id,
 MAX(CASE WHEN Rn = 1 THEN RIGHT(Campaign_name, 5) END) AS CampaignCode1,
 MAX(CASE WHEN Rn = 1 THEN Offer_name END) AS OfferName1,
 MAX(CASE WHEN Rn = 2 THEN RIGHT(Campaign_name, 5) END) AS CampaignCode2,
 MAX(CASE WHEN Rn = 2 THEN Offer_name END) AS OfferName2,
 MAX(CASE WHEN Rn = 3 THEN RIGHT(Campaign_name, 5) END) AS CampaignCode3,
 MAX(CASE WHEN Rn = 3 THEN Offer_name END) AS OfferName3,
 MAX(CASE WHEN Rn = 4 THEN RIGHT(Campaign_name, 5) END) AS CampaignCode4,
 MAX(CASE WHEN Rn = 4 THEN Offer_name END) AS OfferName4
FROM
(
  SELECT Campaign_id, Campaign_name, Offer_name,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Campaign_id ORDER BY REVERSE(Offer_name)) AS Rn
  FROM YourTable
) AS Src
GROUP BY Campaign_id
ORDER BY Campaign_id;
```